# Matlab fsolve with vectors: How to define the function?

Tags: matlab, function

I am trying to understand how fsolve works with vectors. I expected the two functions below to yield the same result but they don't. Where is my mistake?

```
% Define parameters
f1 = 1; f2 = 2; f3 = 3; g1 = 4; g2 = 5; g3 = 6; 

% Starting values
w0 = [3 2];

% Using Function F1
F1 = fsolve(@(w) fun1(w, f1, f2, f3, g1, g2, g3), w0);

% Using Function F2
h1 = [f1 g1];
h2 = [f2 g2];
h3 = [f3 g3];

F2 = fsolve(@(w) fun2(w, h1, h2, h3), w0);

% Define Functions
function F1 = fun1(w, f1, f2, f3, g1, g2, g3)
    F1(1) = f1*w(1) + f2*w(2) + f3;
    F1(2) = g1*w(1) + g2*w(2) + g3;
end

function F2 = fun2(w, h1, h2, h3)
    F2 = h1.*w + h2.*w + h3;
end
```

The result is.

```
F1 =
    1.0000   -2.0000
F2 =
   -1.0000   -0.6667
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your reference is `fun2`, then your `fun1` should be written as below for equivalence

```
function F1 = fun1(w, f1, f2, f3, g1, g2, g3)
    F1(1) = f1*w(1) + f2*w(1) + f3;
    F1(2) = g1*w(2) + g2*w(2) + g3;
end
```

Otherwise, you should rewrite your `fun2` like

```
function F2 = fun2(w, h1, h2, h3)
    F2 = [h1',h2',h3']*[w';1];
end
```